# slider function not running as desired in safari as it does in chrome/firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a `slider` function that automatically runs through a group of list items.
 In **Chrome** and **Firefox**, the resting image is the first one after the automatic rotation. 
 Unfortunately, in **Safari and IE**, it rests on the last image. I thought this might have been a style issue but I'm not using any styles that would cause this. I also thought maybe `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()` was causing the inconsistency. I'm not able to lock down what is the cause.

```
$(function ($) {

    var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
    var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
    var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
    var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

    $('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

    $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

    $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

    function moveLeft() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: + slideWidth
        }, 800, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    function moveRight() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: - slideWidth
        }, 800, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    $('.sa-left').click(function () {
        moveLeft();
        clearInterval(auto);
    });

    $('.sa-right').click(function () {
        moveRight();
        clearInterval(auto);
    });


    var auto = setInterval(moveRight, 1000);

    var stopOnSlide =  slideCount*1000+1000; 

    window.setTimeout(function(){
        clearInterval(auto);

        $( '.sa-left , .sa-right' ).delay(1000).fadeIn('slow');

    }, stopOnSlide);  
});
```

What am I missing here? I've researched this specific issue and haven't found a clue as to what this issue might be.

```
    <div id="container">

        <div id="sliderContainer">
            <div id="slider">
                <div class="slider-arrow sa-left"><img src='arrowLeft.png'/></div>
                <div class="slider-arrow sa-right"><img src='arrowRight.png'/></div>
                <ul>
                  <li id='toggle1'><img src="t1.png"></li>
                  <li id='toggle2'><img src="t2.png"></li>
                  <li id='toggle3'><img src="t3.png"></li>
                </ul> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- crucial scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s0.2mdn.net/ads/studio/Enabler.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

    /<!-- plugin scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/TweenLite.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/TimelineLite.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/plugins/CSSPlugin.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/easing/EasePack.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/draggabilly/1.2.0/draggabilly.pkgd.min.js"></script>

    <!-- custom scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Could you please post your `html` also.

Comment: I didn't think the html was necessary to include but I've added it to the original post.

Comment: Problem was not clear enough that's why i asked to post html. Check the answer. Keep posting if further update needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated JS**

```
$(function ($) {

    var slider = $('#slider ul');
    var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
    var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
    var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
    var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;
    var transitionDuration = 400;
    var sliderDuration = 4000;
    var activeSlide = 1;
    var autoSlide;
    var setAuto = true;



    $('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight, overflow: 'hidden',position:'relative' });

     $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, position: 'absolute'});

     function sliderAnimate() {
        clearInterval(autoSlide);

        slider.animate({
            left: -(activeSlide-1)*slideWidth
        },transitionDuration);

        if(setAuto){
            autoSlideHandler();
        }           

     };

     sliderAnimate();

    function autoSlideHandler(){

        autoSlide = setInterval(function(){

            if(activeSlide<slideCount){
                activeSlide++;
                sliderAnimate();
            }else {
                swapFirstToLast();
                setAuto = false;
                $( '.sa-left , .sa-right' ).fadeIn('slow');
                sliderAnimate()
            }

         },sliderDuration);
    }

    $('.sa-left').click(function () {
        if(activeSlide >1){
            activeSlide--;
            sliderAnimate();
        }else {
            swapLastToFirst();
            sliderAnimate()
        }
    });

    $('.sa-right').click(function () {
        if(activeSlide < slideCount){
            activeSlide++;
            sliderAnimate();
        }else {
            swapFirstToLast();
            sliderAnimate()
        }
    });

    function swapFirstToLast(){
        var firstSlide = slider.find('li:first-child');
        slider.append(firstSlide.clone());
        slider.css('left',-(activeSlide-2)*slideWidth);
        firstSlide.remove()
    }

    function swapLastToFirst(){
        var lastChild = slider.find('li:last-child');
        slider.prepend(lastChild.clone()).css('left',-(activeSlide)*slideWidth);
        lastChild.remove();
    }


});
```

[Working demo using your code](http://jsfiddle.net/shishirmorshed/84ofq5cq/)

[Updated demo(continuous slider)](http://jsfiddle.net/shishirmorshed/jnmejLr2/)

Comment: The problem is: after the slides auto-animate, I want to return back to the initial slide and stop the animation. It works in Chrome and Firefix while it doesn't in Safari. The updated JS removes the setInterval that I was using to stop running the animation after the first cycle, but I need that.

Comment: I have updated my answer & fiddle. Please check now.

Comment: Your code is so much simpler, cleaner and, more importantly, it works across browsers. Thank you for your eyes, brain and help.

Comment: You removed where I was appending and prepending the first clip so that the arrows cycled in either direction. This changes the behavior of what the arrows do once you're at the very end or beginning of the list items. What was you logic in doing so?

Comment: While I like this variant, I don't want to lose the functionality of being able to cycle through with either arrow, which brings me back to my original issue. I'm thinking there is a conflict with the setInterval and setTimeout.

Comment: What i am missing in the `fiddle` provided in my last comment? Do you want  continue sliding in any direction on arrow click?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kennbiv/z356mr2h/40/

The desired effect is to end the auto cycle on the first frame. In Safari, it ends on the correct frame. In Chrome, it ends one frame ahead. The end frame is off by one between browsers and this seems to be due to some issue with setInterval and setTimeout

Comment: Got your point. I have updated my answer again. Hope this time it will work.

Comment: Eureka! That's it, Shishir. Thank you for your help. The lesson I've learned is that setTimeout can be a headache. I'm so happy to see a solution where I don't need it. Thank you again.